# IntentService with Socket.io getting killed after clearing recents

Tags: android, sockets, service

I'm trying to make a notification app that's connected to a server via sockets. I want some service to run on the background whenever my app isn't opened by the user, similar to many email/chat apps, so the user will be able to receive notifications.

I'm having an issue in which the service is getting killed whenever I clear the recent apps.

Here's what I've tried:

- Use IntentService, which I start in onCreate of my main activity
- Call startForeground inside onHandleIntent
- onHandleIntent contains my socket connection start
- Override onStartCommand to return START_STICKY

  ```
  @Override
  protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
      // Socket.io
      mSocket.on("debug-listing", new Emitter.Listener() {
          @Override
          public void call(final Object... args) {
              mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                  @Override
                  public void run() {
                      // I want this to run in the background
                      String msg = (String) args[0];
                      Intent done = new Intent();
                      done.putExtra("title", msg);
                      done.putExtra("id", idCount++);
                      done.setAction("action");
                      sendBroadcast(done); 
                  }
              });
          }
      });

      mSocket.connect();

      Notification n = new Notification.Builder(this)
              .setContentTitle("Test")
              .setContentText("Test")
              .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_ic_notification)
              .build();
      startForeground(421941, n);
  }
  ```

I'm getting notifications whenever my app is open/minimized, but once I clear my recent apps it gets killed. How do I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

I overrode the onCreate function putting all my socket.io event handlers there, as well as registering any broadcast receivers that I want to broadcast to whenever an event happens (aka I want to send a notification).

Inside onStart I call .connect() on my socket variable, and return START_STICKY, which restarts my service when I clear recent apps.

Inside onHandleIntent I don't do anything.

I guess a follow up question is that why do I not do anything inside onHandleIntent (am I not supposed to use IntentService? should I use Service instead), but that can go on another thread. However, more explanation is appreciated!